# How to run a php file forever in ubuntu by command line

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am using web-socket in php to run a chat service problem is when i close the command line the connection also close , is there a solution so that the chat service can run forever .
i am using this command

```
php -q server.php
```

Comment: nohup php -q server.php &

Comment: I'm not sure if cron jobs will help you with this.

Comment: @andrex no , cron job is not sutable for this

Comment: @Cheery thanks dude it workes for me. you can post this as answer

Answer (score 5):

create a php file on your server name it as start_server.php
and post this content

```
            <?php

            $shell_command = "php -q server.php > /dev/null &";
            shell_exec($shell_command);

            ?>
```

now execute this command

php start_server.php

Answer (score 0):

I am using `screen` for running php script and so far I haven't really faced any issues.

> screen is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes (typically interactive shells). Each virtual terminal provides the functions of a DEC VT100 terminal and, in addition, several control functions from the ISO 6429 (ECMA 48, ANSI X3.64) and ISO 2022 standards (e.g. insert/delete line and support for multiple character sets). There is a scrollback history buffer for each virtual terminal and a copy-and-paste mechanism that allows moving text regions between windows.

More about screen [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/screen.htm).

One drawback with using screen is that if you make a change in your script you will have to terminate the virtual terminal and create a new one for the changes to take effect.

Here is a sample code:

```
$ screen -L php /path/to/php/script
```

This will create a new virtual terminal.

Some useful commands:

- To detach screen (once you are in the virtual terminal): `ctrl + a + d`
- To resume screen (from your main terminal once detached): `$ screen -r`
  If there are multiple screens running on your machine the above command should be followed by the pid.tty.host string which is unique for each screen
- To terminate screen: `ctrl + c`
- To list pid.tty.host strings of each terminal: `$ screen -ls`

---